# ASN.1 object identifier values greater than 128

Tags: c#, encoding, binary, cryptography, asn.1

So I understand the way the values are encoded when their values are less than 127. However, after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccertenroll/about-object-identifier, i still don't understand how values greater than 128 are encoded. For example:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.20
```

gets encoded into:

```
2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 15 14
```

How is `311` encoded into `82 37`? When you convert `8237` to decimal, you get `33335`. I don't really understand this part exactly.

Comment: 311 is 0x137.  So the the least significant byte is the same.  It looks like you are using Unicode encoding and the characters definitions are the ascii codes for character 1 to 127.  Unicode characters above 128 are simply different.  The unicode characters the first byte is a group indicator (like Latin Characters) and the second character identifies each character uniquely.

Comment: @jdweng: This is DER encoding of ASN.1 object identifiers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) should help you understand the encoding.

7-bit encoding is used and 8th bit (MSB) used to indicate end of encoding.
`82 37` is in binary `10000010 00110111`. You can see that it is composed of 2 parts. The first part has MSB set to 1 but the second (also the last in this case) has the MSB set to 0 indicating end of encoding. If you decoded that (ignore MSB from first part) it would be `0000 0010 = 256 (2*128)` + `0011 0111 = 55 (2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^5)` = `311`

Comment: 10000010 00110111 remove MSB = 100110111 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^5 + 2^8 = 311